# Question about public and private key signing and verification using ssh

Tags: ssh, key, public

I am trying to use a public and private key generated with the command:
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f rsa_test

I think I understand the private key part but I am having trouble with the public key verification.  I think I have to instantiate an RSAPublicKey.  I am not exactly sure how to do this though.  Do I need to extract something from the public key for verification or can I use it as is?

Thanks.

Comment: I should add this.  Do I need to extract the key from the public key file or do I use the entire file?

Comment: So I worked on this for a little bit and I think I've found the answer.  However, I do need to know where part of the public key file is actually the key.  My resource says it is a 4 byte length and is base 64 encoded.  However, I'm not sure which part of the public file is the key.